Как написать сложение количества если такой товар уже есть в бд?
private void ButtonSklad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     sGrid.ItemsSource = null;
     sGrid.ItemsSource = App.Db.NakladnayPrihods.Local.ToBindingList();

     var nakl = App.Db.NakladnayPrihods.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Tovar1 == Tovar1.Text && 
     n.NameSklad == textBoxMol.Text);
     if (nakl == null)

         App.Db.NakladnayPrihods.Add(new NakladnayPrihod
         {

             NameSklad = textBoxMol.Text,
             Tovar1 = Tovar1.Text,
             KolTov = Col1.Text,
             Izm = Izm.Text,
             Cena1 = Cena1.Text,

         });
}


else { // увеличение нужного свойства объекта nakl }?

Я это понимаю, но как говориться, написать не могу. Мне надо, что KolTov плюсовался. Пока учусь и сложно дается иногда синтаксис.

Что за ORM используете? Какая версия .NET? Для чего вам что-то плюсовать? Это надо в базу данных сохранить или отобразить, или что делать?

сложно дается иногда синтаксис - else nakl.KolTov++;

nakl.KolTov пробовала, выдает ошибку, не возможно применить к стринг, так понимаю надо перевод

nakl.KolTov = (int.Parse(Col1.Text) + int.Parse(nakl.KolTov)).ToString(); но поле, хранящее число не должно быть строкой, у вас ошибка в структуре таблицы базы данных.

Получилось. Спасибо! Я все вокруг да около.
